# How to restrict users switching from su command

Tags: command, local, block, su, rhel8

How can I restrict users switching by `su` command?

Suppose there are 3 users (*root*,*user1* and *user2*) only *root* and *user1* can switch by using `su` command. *root* or *user1* should not be able to switch to *user2* by using `su` command.

```
root@instance# su - user1 *ok*
```

```
user1@instance$ sudo su -   *ok*
```

```
root@instance# su - user2 *should be blocked*
```

```
user1@instance$ sudo su - user2   *should be blocked*
```

How can I do this?

**OS is RHEL 7**

Comment: You can't prevent root to do anything. Other users require the password, so don't give them the password.

Comment: Can't you give them [sudo access](https://www.howtogeek.com/111479/htg-explains-whats-the-difference-between-sudo-su/) to a restricted set of options?  [Where su is not one].

Answer (score 2):

As you know, **root user is the conventional name of the user who has all rights or permissions (to all files and programs) in all modes (single- or multi-user).**

The *root* user can do many things an ordinary user cannot, such as changing the ownership of files and binding to ports numbered below 1024. The etymology of the term may be that *root* is the only user account with permission to modify the root directory of a Unix system. This includes `su` command to switch to another user.

For that reason, you can't restrict the use of the `su`command to *root* user.

Now talking about *user1* you can restrict the use of the `su` command removing the user from the **wheel group** due to any user on that group heritage the *root* level privileges.

Have fun!